# how to call function ever 1 mint when page direct also

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, setinterval

We developing phone-Gap app.We have 4 pages.We need ever 1 mint Post Current latitude and longitude.We know how to Post values to server.We know how to get latitude and longitude ever 1 mint Using this

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError, options);`

Now we need ever 1 mint call to ajax call So We tried like this

```
window.setInterval(function(){
      call();
    }, 5000);
      function call(){

        //ajax call for server posting 
    }
```

We have 3 pages.Above code place page1,code working nice.But When go to second page ajax call not working .Please any one guide me.How to When page redirect also Page1 Call function call ever 1 mint

Comment: put it in a shared script file and call it in both the pages

Comment: @ArunPJohny no need to other page My problem is suppose When page1 is open  after 5mints call count 1 and then next 5mints count 2 but When go to page2 and then come back page1 it's again count 1

Comment: then you need to have a local/session storage which can be used to remember to previously used count

Comment: @ArunPJohny We need is setInterval continuously Work ever 1mint .When we got to any page  until my app closed Please give me any idea

Comment: store your page1 count to localstorage before go to page2

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira We need When we go to  page2, also 
page1 count will be increase automatically because When we spend 10m time in page2 We missed posting 10m Data .Please guide me

Comment: no. i mean store your count in page1 then use it on interval on page2. in your call function, it will probably like this (1 minute interval) `if (count===60000) then run ajax;reset your count to 0` but before that, you must set your interval to 1000 (1 second)

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira ok i will try as you said .I have one doubt .We need ever 5 mints get latitude and longitude  and then post ever 5 mints .We done  in page1. But When we go to page2 no getting values  and no posting .First Please tell me if's possible getting latitude and longitude values and posting values ,after page redirect also

Answer (score 0):

You would use setInterval like this

```
setInterval( call, 500 );
```

'call' is the name of your function.

Also, it's best to declare your call function before the setInterval.

Comment: thanks for reply suppose i have 10 pages setInterval placed in first page,But When go to page 2 to 10 setInterval not working .We need is setInterval Work until my app closed Please give me any idea